There exist only one dream that all Americans share" vs "All Americans have only one and the same dream"
For the following examples, let $A$ be the set of all Americans, $D$ the set of all dreams, and $H(a,d)$ be the proposition $\text{American } a \in A \text{ has dream } d \in D.$

There exist only one dream that all Americans have (they may have more than one dream, but there is only one that they all share).
I would translate this as: $\exists !d \in D, \forall a \in A, H(a,d)$

All Americans have only one dream and this dream is the same for all Americans (so there is no American with more than one dream).
I would translate this as: $\forall a \in A, \exists !d \in D, H(a,d)$. Here I'm not sure if flipping the first two part really makes a difference in meaning.


Are these correct? If not, how to correctly express these two nuances?

Your second statement doesn't imply that all Americans have the same dream. You could translate sentence two as $\exists d \in D. \forall a \in A. \forall d' \in D. H(a, d') \Leftrightarrow d = d'$.



There exist only one dream that all Americans have (they may have more than one dream, but there is only one that they all share).
I would translate this as: $\exists !d \in D, \forall a \in A, H(a,d)$



Correct.


All Americans have only one dream and this dream is the same for all Americans (so there is no American with more than one dream).
I would translate this as: $\forall a \in A, \exists !d \in D, H(a,d)$



Your translation is logically weaker than the given statement. A correct attempt (these are equivalences):

There's a dream that every American has AND every American has exactly one dream
$∃d{\in }D\,∀a {\in }A\,Had \quad∧\quad ∀a {\in }A\,∃d {\in  }D\,∀q {\in  }D\,(Haq ↔ q=d)$
$∃d {\in  }D\,∀a {\in }A\,∃r {\in  }D\,(Had \;∧\; ∀q {\in  }D\,(Haq ↔ q=r))$
$∃d {\in  }D\,∀a {\in }A\,∃r {\in  }D\,(d=r \;∧\; ∀q {\in  }D\,(Haq ↔ q=r))$
$∃d {\in  }D\,∀a {\in }A\,∀q {\in  }D\,(Haq ↔ q=d).$


Do you see a way to do this also without using $\wedge$?

@Tripola That final simplification (the last bullet point) doesn't use the '∧' symbol (though the given verbal statement contains the word 'and').
